# Creating a view using overlay JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I want to create a view in swing like in the picture. I managed to create the using three horizontal panels. My question is that I can create same view using only one horizontal panel ?[image]

Comment: Are the three rectangles in picture a container which can hold other components?

Comment: Yes they are jpanels. What I want to achieve is that the three panels to be one

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that does what it does with 3 panels.  I *still* do not understand the question.

Comment: I want to overlay the two black panels over the horizontal panel.

Comment: *"I want.."* S-S-C-C-E.

Comment: What do you mean by _"I managed to create the using three horizontal panels"_ I only see 1 horizontal panel in the picture?

Comment: They are three horizontal panels

Answer (score 1):

In `Swing`, no you cannot do it with a single `JPanel`.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own layout manager, like they show in [*Creating a Custom Layout Manager*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/custom.html).